# iftop never stops working

Tags: networking, process, htop

I recently learned about `iftop` and used it for monitoring my wifi data usage few times today.

```
sudo iftop -i wlp2s0
```

is how I call it. After 4-5 opening closing of `iftop`, I figured out that my computer(Ubuntu 20.04, btw) started burning, an checking `htop` showed me that all those `iftop` processes were indeed wasn't being terminated and were running at background and consuming my cpu power.

After this, I made few trials and saw that it is not actually quitting working.

[image]

This is a view from htop, when I opened and closed an `iftop`. As seen, it still shows up there.

The only way I managed to terminate it is opening htop with sudo, and then using F9(kill).

By the way, I could not able to see those iftops are open on system monitor. I just saw them when I first opened htop.

Any idea on what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the tip, at least i've managed to close it (i was missing sudo)